# How to reply with a keyboard in telegram bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot that is supposed to show keyboard1at at `/faq` command and at each `/faq` keyboard option to visualize some text (the text is not added yet).

This is the first bot i'm creating and there are some problems:

1. the bot does not listen to the commands continuously
2. it does not show keyboard1 at `/faq`
3. another strange thing, it keeps keyboard options that are not present in the code anymore, i mean i can still see the inlinekeyboard that was created in previous code versions and i don't know how to get rid of it. Could someone help with it please? Here is the code:

> ```
> import telebot
> from tkinter import *
> from telegram.ext import Updater
> from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
> from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
>
> bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
> updater = Updater('TOKEN', use_context=True)
> updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', ...))
>
> @bot.message_handler(commands=['help','start'])
> def send_welcome(message):
>     if message.text == "/start":
>         updater.send_message(message.chat.id,'Some welcome text')
>     elif message.text == "/help":
>             updater.send_message(message.chat.id,
>                              'list of all commands')
>   elif message.text == "/lastin":
>             updater.send_message(message.chat.id,
>                              'some text')
> def build_menu(buttons,
>                n_cols,
>                header_buttons=None,
>                footer_buttons=None):
>     menu = [buttons[i:i + n_cols] for i in range(0, len(buttons), n_cols)]
>     if header_buttons:
>         menu.insert(0, [header_buttons])
>     if footer_buttons:
>         menu.append([footer_buttons])
>     return menu
>
> keyboard1 = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Question 1', callback_data='q1')],
>             [InlineKeyboardButton('Question 2', callback_data='q2')],
>             [InlineKeyboardButton('Question 3', callback_data='q3')],
>             [InlineKeyboardButton('Question 4', callback_data='q4')]]
> reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(keyboard1, n_cols=2))
>
> @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
> def send_text(message):
>     if message.text == "/faq":
>         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text = 'FAQ', reply_markup = reply_markup)
>     elif message.text == "/lastin":
>         bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo='https://telegram.org/img/t_logo.png')
>
>
> updater.start_polling()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using both [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) and [telebot](https://github.com/KyleJamesWalker/telebot) simultaneously, which might cause your issues.

As `telebot` does not yet seem to support all features you are using (e.g. [send_photo](https://github.com/KyleJamesWalker/telebot/blob/414a346357d4f474cdaf6d843c812454b20d2456/telebot/__init__.py#L160)), you might want to consider using `python-telegram-bot` exclusively.

Comment: Thanks! what should i import then and how to define bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')? many thanks

Comment: You can just remove that line as well as the telebot import. The `Updater` and `CommandHandler` which you already use are sufficient for the basics. You can also remove the `message_handler` annotated functions, and register your commands like the `start` command. See the [tutorial](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot) and the [echobot2 example bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/echobot2.py).

Comment: apologise for a stupid question, but in case telebot import will be removed, @bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) has an issue since bot is not defined, what should be used instead of it?

Comment: Also remove those, since they are used to map commands to functions, which the `python-telegram-bot` does e.g. using the `add_handler` method, which you can see in the example bots like the mentioned `echobot2`.